# R: How to set "pdfviewer" to Skim?

Tags: r

I couldn't figure out how to set `pdfviewer` to Skim (Mac OS X) in R. Does anyone know how to specify `pdfviewer` to get Skim to open pdf documents? The variable `pdfviewer` is contained in ~/.Rprofile.

**Solution**
My .Rprofile looks like this:

```
options(repos=c(CRAN="http://cran.ch.r-project.org",
        BioC="http://www.bioconductor.org",
        Omegahat="http://www.omegahat.org/R"),
        pdfviewer=path.expand("~/bin/skim"),
        browser="Chrome")
```

Comment: Your `options()` is plain wrong as you need to close a `)` before you go from repos to the other two.  If in doubt, use several statements :)

Comment: Dear Dirk, thanks, I changed the file an a wrong way when editing it. It now works and I posted the solution above. Is there no simpler way (without having to download a file)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (**edit**: used `path.expand` as suggested by Dirk):

```
dir.create("~/bin")
download.file("http://links.tedpavlic.com/shell_scripts/skim",
              dest="~/bin/skim")
Sys.chmod("~/bin/skim","0755")
system("~/bin/skim")  ## test: should get a usage message
## Usage: skim [-help] [-a] [-o] FILE [LINE [SOURCE]]
options(pdfviewer=path.expand("~/bin/skim"))
```

Test:

```
library(bbmle)
vignette("mle2")
```

If this works you can modify your `~/.Rprofile` file accordingly.

Comment: Regarding the `~`, the function you want is path.expand() and not everything (eg `system` may be one of the bad boys) calls it for you though some of the data readers etc do -- so we always expect it.

Comment: Dear Ben, that's quite funny: I wanted to open the mle2 vignette and then realized the problem with skim (and then you replied :-) )

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 options(pdfviewer="skim")  # add path and options as needed
```

in your `~/.Rprofile` file.

Comment: Dear Dirk, thanks a lot for helping. I obtain an error with your version; I guess the quotes should be around `skim`, not `pdfviewer` (?). I tried this and now I don't obtain an error anymore, but the pdf is still opened with xpdf, not skim. Well, actually, there are still errors `Error: No paper information available - using defaults`

Comment: Yes, indeed, now fixed -- and you may need a full path if skim is some add-on.

Comment: Yes.  skim is an add-on, and MacOS applications are not by default as command-line-friendly as you're used to.  There's probably a slightly less bells-and-whistles possibility than the script I suggest above, but it's not even as easy as just finding the full path to the Skim executable (I think)

Comment: Dear Ben, your code below works, but only if I execute everything (including the `options(pdfviewer=...`-line) in R. Do I have to put in *everything* into `.Rprofile`? Because if I only have the `pdfviewer=path.expand(...)`- line in `.Rprofile`, then (after a restart) it does not work anymore. That would be a pity since I then have to have internet access.

Comment: That's weird.  Not sure why, might not get a chance to check soon.  I don't see why the effects wouldn't be permanent -- if you check in a terminal, is `~/bin/skim` still there and usable?

Comment: Dear Ben, thanks a lot, it now works (the other error I had in .Rprofile caused the problem)